# Fade Animation when click in Aframe

Tags: aframe

> Trying to move from one a-sky to another and I want that when I click on the circle i the current a-sky should fade moving to the next a-sky image. Trying to do that but isn't working?
> Cut it short am trying to build a VR tour with Aframes.
> The circle I created are the hotspots that allows you to change a-sky image

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function nextScene() {
              
              document.getElementById("sky-1").setAttribute("repeat","2")
              document.getElementById("scene1").setAttribute("visible", "false");
              document.getElementById("scene2").setAttribute("visible", "true");
            }
            function nextScene1() {
                document.getElementById("scene1").setAttribute("visible", "false");
                  document.getElementById("scene2").setAttribute("visible", "true");
            
            }
        </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="//unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
        <a-scene>
        <a-entity id="Locomotion">
            <a-camera
                movement-controls="controls:checkpoint"
                checkpoint-controls="mode:animate; animateSpeed:5.0"
                >
                <a-cursor> </a-cursor>
            </a-camera>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="scene1" material="opacity: 1">
            <a-sky
                id="skybox"
                src="./img/1.jpeg"
                checkpoint-controls="mode:animate; animateSpeed:13.0"
                >
                <a-animation
                    id="sky-1"
                    attribute="material.opacity"
                    dur="1000"
                    direction="alternate"
                    to="2"
                    ></a-animation>
            </a-sky>
            <a-sphere
                checkpoint="offset:0 1.5 0"
                color="#500"
                position="0 0.1 -3"
                rotation="-90 0 0"
                onclick="nextScene()"
                >
            </a-sphere>
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity
            id="scene2"
            visible="false"
            dur="1500"
            from="1.0"
            to="0.0"
            begin="fadeIn"
            >
            <a-sky id="skybox" src="./img/2.jpeg">
                <a-animation
                    attribute="material.opacity"
                    dur="500"
                    begin="fade"
                    to="1"
                    repeat="0"
                    ></a-animation>
            </a-sky>
            <a-circle
                color="#050"
                checkpoint="offset:0 1.5 0"
                position="-5 0.1 -3"
                rotation="-90 0 0"
                onclick="nextScene1()"
                >
            </a-circle>
        </a-entity>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. The snippet is not working :(
2. You're importing a-frame `0.8.0` and `1.2.0` at the same time
I'd stick with the newest one (`1.2.0`) and use the [animation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#sidebar) component instead of the deprecated `<a-animation>`

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski well I did removing it but nothing happen, because you can go ahead and remove it and see it doesn't still work. If you check this link https://jsfiddle.net/franky_brown/pqe6onmx/4/ u will see the corrected code and output but it doesn't work.